# CSS background-size cover and background-position

Tags: html, css, background-image

HTML:

```css
#backgroundproduct {
  position: fixed;
  top: 5%;
  left: 5%;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  z-index: 12;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top;
}
```

```html
<div id="backgroundproduct" style="background-image: url(http://example.com/example.jpg)">
```

I'm using a images as a background image, only the lower part of the image is more important than the top.

How can I make the background go up a little?

Comment: background-position can accept two pixel or percent based numbers.

Comment: And is there a way to "zoom out"

Comment: background-size accept pixel based numbers too

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If the bottom is more important: `background-position: bottom;`

`background-position` also allows percentage values: `0% 0%;` by default.

> The first value is the horizontal position and the second value is the
>   vertical. The top left corner is 0% 0%. The right bottom corner is
>   100% 100%. If you only specify one value, the other value will be 50%.

You should try `background-position: 0% -10%;`

Comment: thank you fixed it i was just thinking wrong. And is there a way to "zoom out" so you see more of the picture ?

Comment: Yes, you could use `background-size` with percentages. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Comment: thank you some times its just hard to find when you don't know were your looking for

Comment: How can you only specify one value?

Comment: Such as `background-position: 20%;` it would mean `background-position: 20% 50%;`

Answer (score 10):

You can use:

```
background-position: center bottom;
```

Comment: oke that's just stupid of my not thinking about this. thanks!

Comment: You can use background-size: contain; to fit the background in div. Though, the image may look disproportionate because stretching may occur. This is a CSS3 property though.

Comment: `background-size: contain` maintains the bitmap's original aspect ratio

Comment: @pmont, but it doesn't cover the whole parent element.

Comment: Try `background-size: cover`.  That's what I've used to cover the entire parent background.  It stretches the bitmap if necessary while maintaining the original aspect ratio.

Answer (score 2):

Just to be clear, background-position percentages are calculated against BOTH the image and the background container.  So, background-position: 25% 25%; would find the 25% point for both X and Y on the background container and align the image's 25%,25% point on top of that point.

Comment: If I specify pixel values,(x, y), will it find the (x, y) position on the image and set it to the containers (50%, 50%) position?