# Text on background. How to keep it on the same position when reducing the browser

Tags: css, position

Here you have a background and a text:
http://freshp.webflow.io/

The text looks good and keeps its position even when you lower the browser from right to left. The problem is that I do not want it to be there. But when I move the text from the current position, and put it on the desired position, it loses its starting position when I have reduced the browser. It does not have that problem now. Nothing changes on the way when I reduce the browser.

Right now, I've got it to the current position through flex options (justify center, align center)
But the desired position is a few centimeters further down and a few centimeters from the center. I've tried to place it there "manually" through margin, padding, positioning, but it turned out to be a bad idea, because then the text does not hold its position, when I decrease the browser.

What can I do about this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS background-size cover and background-position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13924626/css-background-size-cover-and-background-position)

Comment: Also, you might find https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376253/stretch-and-scale-css-background helpful.

Comment: The answers were not relevant to the question. Please try again

Comment: Could you put this behavior from freshp and your attempt to adapt it into a simpe example on jsfiddle to make it easier to understand what you do and easier to play around with it?